# Method in a JSP requires return String from deployed applet

Tags: java, jsp, applet, struts

I am trying to retrieve string data from a deployed applet with a method that returns the current logged on user.

How do I populate the Java string variable I have on the same page with the applet method return?

```jsp
<applet width=1 height=1 code="com.myapp.struts.getLogin.class"></applet> 
<% String userName = "APPLET RETURN VALUE" %>
```

Comment: 1) `com.myapp.struts.getLogin.class` should be ideally be the Fully Qualified Name, I.E. `com.myapp.struts.getLogin`2) Why is it an applet knows who the user is, but not the JSP? 3) The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The JSP scriptlet is evaluated on the server-side. The applet is executed on the client-side.

So this cannot be done. You will need some other mechanism to exchange this information.

You could for instance consider to make a network connection from your applet and back to the same server it came from. E.g. a HTTP request from the applet to POST the desired information back to your server.